# Firebase - How to get property after querying by child

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

My firebase table is like the following:

```
posts
  randomId
    username
    age
```

I want to be able to query by child and then instead of returning the entire object just return the property I need.

```
subscribePostsAgeForUsername(username: string): Observable<string[]>{
  return this.af.database.list('posts', {
    query: {
        orderByChild: 'username',
        equalTo: username
    }
});
```

This as of now just returns the entire object. I just want to return the ages.

Comment: You are thinking Firebase like a relational database which is not. If you want only ages you may have to change your schema so that you get desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map operator from rxjs

```
return this.af.database.list('posts', {
    query: {
        orderByChild: 'username',
        equalTo: username
    }
}).map(posts => posts.map(post => post.property_you_need));
```

**Note:** When you use this method you still get the entire object from angularfire list and just simplified it with map. If your main reason is improving performance by only getting the property, it doesn't work that way on firebase. You need to restructure your database based on your needs.